# TPM and storage of keys

Tags: trust, trusted-computing

A TPM hardware device has very limited non-volatile protected memory just sufficient to store the EK (Endorsement Key) and SRK (Storage Root Key). How does a TPM allow nearly unlimited number of symmetric keys to be safely stored on an otherwise very vulnerable HDD?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The Storage Root Key (SRK) is used to wrap TPM protected keys which can be stored outside the TPM.](http://www.fidis.net/resources/deliverables/hightechid/int-d37002/doc/9/) That data stored outside the TPM can be decrypted by passing it back through the TPM again for a decryption operation.

Keys wrapped by the SRK can themselves be used to wrap other keys, too. This method of wrapping can be used to create a key hierarchy of parent key and child keys. To load a child, first load its parent. Once the child is loaded, the parent key can be unloaded from the TPM to free up TPM chip resources.